# How to tell if a matrix of a certain rank contains a certain kernel and image?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm struggling with the following question
True or False: There exists a 3x4 matrix A of rank 2 such that ker(A) contains the vector v = $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    1\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and image(A) contains the vector w = $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    1\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm not sure how to go about this without coming up with matrices that would possibly fit these conditions. How else can you go about this question?

Comment: Clearly $3\times 4$ matrices of dimension 2 exist.  And such a matrix would have not trivial kernel and image.  These two vectors are as good as any others.  But to find an example shouldn't be hard either.  $\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1 \\1&-1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** You can proceed naively. The image is the span of the columns, so we can ensure that $\pmatrix{1\\1\\1} \in \operatorname{image}(A)$ by taking that to be its first column:
$$A = \pmatrix{1 & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{24} \\ 1 & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\ 1 & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}}.$$
On the other hand, imposing $$\pmatrix{0\\0\\0} = A \pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1} = \pmatrix{1 & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{24} \\ 1 & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\ 1 & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}}\pmatrix{1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 1} $$
and multiplying out the r.h.s. gives three independent affine constraints on the $a_{ij}$, and finding a solution to these is just arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

How about $\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\1&0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Not sure about how else to go about it, than providing an example.